# Dir="rtl" messes up viewport functionality on mobile pages

Tags: mobile, viewport, arabic, right-to-left

We are creating a RTL version of our site pages for Arabic, and have found that using  solves many layout problems, but with the side effect that on mobile devices, our viewport code  no longer results in correct scaling on initial load (testing on iphone). If we remove the rtl tag, the scaling returns to being perfect. Here's an sample page:

http://www.tribeofheart.org/sr/pkj_arabic_m.htm

We've tried several commonly suggested variants of viewport code for mobile devices, but so far no luck. For example, these did not resolve the issue:

Any suggestions would be so greatly appreciated.

cayugaman

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your
 question. Great questions tend to generate quicker, better answers from the community. - For Starters, please include a [mcve] to your question. Without it, it is nearly impossible to know *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: We have solved the problem. It was being caused by code included in our mailchimp subscription section that inserts an item 5000 pixels to the left as an apparent anti-spambot strategy. We simply altered the code to insert the item 5000 pixels to the right and the issue was resolved.

Comment: that's the reason an [mcve] is needed. There are too many variables at play that a simple link will not tell you.... glad you figured it out.

Comment: I had some help getting there. I will try to do better with problem definition next time...